# "Twilight Zone" episode with time-stopping aliens, a test pilot and a woman wonder at how marvelous things look while stopped

Tags: episode-identification, the-twilight-zone

There is an old black and white episode of *The Twilight Zone* in which a test pilot and a woman in a car find themselves stopped a mere instant before a devastation crash would have surely killed them. They are in separate locations but close enough to eventually meet up. They quickly realize that time has stopped though they are still moving normally.

During this time they explore a small town and marvel at how everything looks while stopped. As I remember, they find the control room for some sort of experiment that was being conducted. This is where the aliens come in. If I remember right you never really clearly see the aliens but their voices can be heard. The man and woman also discover multiple accidents about to occur but they are powerless to stop them. I distinctly remember a little girl on a tricycle riding on the sidewalk in front of a fire station and an unmanned fire engine about to roll over her.

Comment: Sounds right.... I didn't think to look for Outer Limits because I always had it in my head it was Twilight Zone. Thank you @Richard

Comment: No worries. You may have an upvote to reward you for your excellent description.